# Xamarin Android C# Multi touch disabled during a drag & drop

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, drag

My drag & drop function works well, but during the drag i cannot press buttons or activate others xml controls until drag & drop ends.

How can i solve the issue?

```
    void DraggedControlsMovedToDropZone(object sender, View.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var evt = e.Event;
        switch (evt.Action)
        {
            case DragAction.Ended:
            case DragAction.Started:
                e.Handled = true;
                break;

            // the dragged control enter the drop zone
            case DragAction.Entered:
            {
                 //do stuff
            }
            break;

            // the dragged control exit the drop zone
            case DragAction.Exited:
            {
                //do stuff
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your user really need to be able to interact with other UI elements during the middle of a drag-and-drop?  Is this something other apps allow?

Comment: @Jason Yes if dragging an element ask to the user an input choice.
My drag & drop works like a joystick. Moving xml control on other controls i must be allowed to interact to the view.